# How can I check if my eventhandler is canceled or not called by RaisePropertyChanged() in SL?

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, prism

With my colleague we are having a problem with SilverLight regarding the NotificationObject of Prism.

Our problem is;

- We bind an event handler to one of our DependencyProperties
- Then we call RaiseChangedEvent in the setter
- When we debug, we see that eventhandler is assigned and it is called when the proerty value is changed.
- But when we chage the property value once agian from in the UI, this time we see that our event handler is not called.

So we want to be sure:

- If event handler is still binded (unless it is not null, we believe it is binded)
- If it is binded why the event is cancelled or why our anonymous event handler method is not called again (the breakpoint is not hit)

  You can see the code snippets below.

  My question is:

  Is there a way to see why the RaisePropertyChanged("MyProperty"); is not calling an eventhandler assigne to this DependencyProperty called Requestor? Any suggestions?

  If I generalize: **Is it possible to step into RaisePropertyChanged("Requestor"); call so that what it does and where it exits**?

See my code snippets:

```
// My dependency property in my ViewModel
public CompanyEntity MyProperty
{
    get { return _MyProperty; }
    set
    {
        _MyProperty = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("MyProperty");
    }
}


// And my Dependency Property Event handler setting in my user control:
public static readonly DependencyProperty FactoryProperty =
DependencyProperty.Register("Factory", typeof (FactoryEntity), typeof (FactoryPicker),
    new PropertyMetadata((x, y) =>
            {
                // Some settings and processes
            }));
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess: don't you have to coerce as explained in http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/57516/146193.aspx?

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have missed the Mode=TwoWay declaration at binding.